# How to make Google display only Country-specific search results based on user's location

Tags: search, seo, google-search

My question goes like this:

I own a multinational company with the following websites

```
www.abc.com/us/,
www.abc.com/uk/,
www.abc.com/apac/,
```

I advertise my product (let's name it "device") on each of my above regional websites like

```
www.abc.com/us/device/
www.abc.com/uk/device/
www.abc.com/apac/device/
```

Content on the above webpages is almost the same albeit some minor differences.

When a user from US searches "device" using Google Search, Google Search result returns all the above three URLs

```
www.abc.com/us/device
www.abc.com/uk/device
www.abc.com/apac/device
```

I do not want this to happen as it confuses the user and would want Google to display only www.abc.com/us/device for the **US user** in his search results,www.abc.com/uk/ for the **UK user** and so on.

What changes do I need to make on my webpage source for Google to display only my United States website (www.abc.com/us/device) in the search results (for US user)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO, not programming. SEO questions may be asked on [Webmasters.SE](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.